# SQL Server database unique row with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with structure like below:

Table 1

```
Field Name  |  Type
BrandID     |  int       >> Unique Identifier
BrandName   |  nvarchar
BrandAlias  |  nvarchar
```

and Table 2

```
Field Name  |   Type
ModelID     |   int      >> Unique Identifier
ModelName   |   nvarchar
ModelAlias  |   nvarchar 
ModelBrand  |   int      >> Linked to Table 1 BrandID
```

Table 1 stores car brands like **Mercedes Benz**, and Table 2 stores model names like **S500, C200, ...**

Now the problem is that user and define a model multiple times. For example a user can define Mercedes Benz S500 as many times as he wants. I can't make **ModelAlias** column as unique, because a model can have same name between two manufacturers.

I want the table 1 to be like this:

```
1   |   Lancer Evolution X   |   lancer-evolution-x   |   2001
2   |   Galant               |   galant               |   2001
```

In this table I have **Mitsubishi Lancer Evolution X** and now user shouldn't be able to add this car again, but user may add ***XYZ Lance Evolution X** where **XYZ** is a different brand.

How can I handle this?

Comment: why not a composite `unique key (modelbrand, modelalias)`?

Comment: As a side note, it appears you are using uniqueidentifiers as your primary key. If this is also the clustered index you need to be aware of the massive fragmentation of your indexes this brings with it. There are tons of articles out there discussing this. Here is one of them. http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/clustered-indexes-based-upon-guids

Comment: I think he meant the ID was a "unique identifier" (i.e. Primary Key, a unique column value), not that the column datatype was "uniqueidentifier".  The example showed integers for that column, and the definition is "int" in the table definition.   Poor choice of words perhaps.